# Exclude Specific Updates from Change Data Capture

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cdc, change-data-capture

I have a proof of concept application which monitors its database for changes using Change Data Capture and transmits these changes using a service bus.  The application also receives notifications from the bus and commits these changes to the local database.

The problem is that when the application commits changes to the local database, the changes then show up in CDC causing the application to retransmit the changes on the bus.

Is there a reliable way to exclude specific changesets from CDC?

I would like to avoid making changes to the source table schema if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution to this problem built into CDC.

In the end I settled for performing updates within a transaction and retrieving the new lsn value for each update whilst within the transaction.  After this I ignore changes for the lsns caused by my own updates.